# Можно ли использовать другие объекты изнутри Service?

Tags: android, service, android-service

Вопрос в следующем: имеется foreground Service. Можно ли внутри этого сервиса обращаться к различным синглтонам и пр.? Т.е. не уничтожатся ли эти синглтоны, если приложение полностью закроют, а сервис будет продолжать работать?